# Persisting variable values between scenarios in capybara

Tags: capybara

I have the code below

if "#{w}" != emailofuser
     globalVariableforsecemail("#{w}")
   end
def globalVariableforsecemail(useremail)
   $secUserEmail = useremail + "rms.com"
end

The problem I have is the first time the scenario is run , it succeeds, but the second time I run the scenario $secUserEmail value does not get input onto the text box. I want to use a variable across scenarios in a feature file and run the feature multiple times, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It's best to avoid global variables across scenarios.

If you really want to do it, just put a global variable in your background/before block in your feature spec

Comment: I want to set the value ofa variable in Scenario 1 and use in Scenario 2.  Otherwise it will end up as a big scenario. During execution of scenario 1 I capture the value and I want to use the value in scenario 2 I tried rack_session_access did not work either.

Comment: If you use a global in scenario 1 such as $email it should be available in scenario 2 as well.